# How to check user token in Angular?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, jwt, angularjs-http

I generated token with JWT using node and angular, and can't check if user is authorized.

Node:

```
module.exports.authenticate = function(req, res) {
    var user = new User(req.body);
    User.findOne({
        username: req.body.username
    }, function(err, user) {
        if (err) throw err;

        if (!user) {
            res.json({ success: false, message: 'Authentication failed. User not found.' });
        }
        else if (user) {
            if (user.password != req.body.password) {
                res.json({ success: false, message: 'Authentication failed. Wrong password.' });
            }
            else {
                var token = jwt.sign(user, config.secret, {
                    expiresIn: 60*60*24
                });

                res.json({
                    success: true,
                    token: token
                });
            }
        }
    });
};
```

Angular:

```
$http(req)
            .then(function (response) {
                console.log(response.data.success);
                if(response.data.success) {
                    var user = localStorage.setItem('token', JSON.stringify(response.data));
                    token = localStorage.getItem('token');
                    // console.log('User info: ', JSON.parse(getuser));
                    // window.location = "/dashboard";
                    return response.data;
                }
            }, function (response) {

            }
        );
    }
```

How can I check token when I change route?

And generically how can I use Token?

Answer (score 2):

Angular ui-router provides `$routeChangeStart` event while you change a route. You can use it in the following way.

```
$rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function (event, next, current){
   //you can code here something to be run on changing routes
}
```

You might want to have a look [here](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#events-1) for detailed event documentation.

Regarding a more generic implementation , you can create a service to keep your token at the time of login or whenever you get it. Thereafter you can keep getting the token from the service for any future comparisons.

Answer (score 0):

you should install  "cookie-parser"

```
npm i cookie-parser
```

and go to index.js file and add

```
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
app.use(cookieParser());
```

it works for me